# HMLHttpRequest cannot load. I'm trying to POST request a JSON object to firebase

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, firebase

I'm trying to POST request a JSON object to firebase, but I see this error:

```
ERROR: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://booksme.firebaseio.com/books/. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://www.wawapps.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here's my JS Code:

```
var name = "test";
var obj = {
    author : name
};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://booksme.firebaseio.com/books/", true);
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
xhr.onloadend = function() {
    alert("done");
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add `.json` onto the URL, as the [REST API explains](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api-quickstart.html)? Does that resolve the issue? How about when you set the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain` as required by [HTTP access control spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests) when performing a POST op?

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible causes of this issue, so it's hard to give specific advice, but here are a couple things that you can try.

1. Add `.json` onto the URL (per the [REST API docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/)).
2. Set the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`.

If neither of those work, please update your question with more detail.